# Fire onbeforeunload event in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, event

I have an lwc component with a form in it.
I want to fire an `onbeforeunload` event when pressing "discard", to show the stanard chrome modal.

Is it possible in lightning web components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use beforeunload for that purpose. It would only fire when the user leaves salesforce completely. You can use a normal onclick handler with the confirm method:

```
cancel(event) {
  if(confirm('Discard your changes?')) {
    // navigate away now
  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```